# Window set interval crashes my browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, rest, webix

I have a JavaScript file in which I am calling a Python method inside `window.setinterval()`. The python method exists on my server and returns large data every time the call is made. It works fine initially and after a point of time, my browser crashes. Is there a solution for this?

JavaScript code:

```
webix.ui({
    view:"datatable",
    id : "component_id",
    cols : [some_columns]
});

window.setInterval({
    var result = webix.ajax().sync().post("my_python_func()");
    $$("component_id").parse(result.responseText);
},500);
```

Python code:

```
my_python_func():
    #subscibe_to_amps_server
    return big_data
```

Comment: What is the interval set at? Can you post some more code?

Comment: Probably a memory leak. You will need to post the code or else this question is not answerable.

Comment: setInterval will fire every x milliseconds no matter what,  so if say you told setInterval to fire every 100ms, and your python method takes 200ms, with Javascript generally been async, you will most likely end up chasing your tail.  One idea is inside the call were you async call to the python is going on, set a flag say called  callingPython or similar, and then when the Python process has finished reset the flag,  now check this flag is false on your setInterval method before calling the Python method again.  Hope that makes sense, it's late here.. :)

Comment: Another option, is use setTimeout instead, and re-call the setTimeout  when your Python response has finished.

Comment: *".ajax().sync()"* - You seem to be using synchronous Ajax. Don't. (But do do the `setTimeout()` thing that Keith mentioned.)